# Can't set a default value to a parameter?

Tags: python

```
def generate_password(size=5):
    generated_password = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(size))
    return generated_password
   

generate_password()
```

So I have this function that should generate a password with *size* letters. I assigned a standard value of 5 to that parameter, when I call the function however and don't give size any other value it won't use 5, but instead throw an Exception. Does anyone see the error?

It throws this:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
  File "C:\Users\dirks\.vscode\import random.py", line 14, in generate_password
    generated_password = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(size))
  File "C:\Users\dirks\.vscode\import random.py", line 21, in <module>
    generate_password()
```

Answer (score 2):

You used the wrong function from `random`.  `choices` returns a list; `choice` returns an element.  You were trying to `join` a series of five lists, each of which contains a one-letter string.

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating `random.choice` and `random.choices`:

```
>>> ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=5))
'lrx0s'

>>> ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(5))
'ZI6d2'
```

One will take the size of as an additional argument; the other needs to be called once for each character you want.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!